# React Native Inline Text Link

Tags: react-native

I need to link up a selection text from within a `Text` component to point to an external URL.

I have included a `TouchableOpacity` and specified a width and height as required, however the `TouchableOpacity` now seems to overlap the adjacent text.

Example:

```
<Text>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => {Linking.openURL('http://www.example.com/')}} 
        style={{width: 108, height: 11}}>
     <Text>
           consectetur adipiscing
     </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity> 
    elit. Fusce congue malesuada euismod.
</Text>
```

What's the best way to keep `TouchableOpacity`s inline within `Text` components?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What about like this?

```
import { Text, Linking } from 'react-native';

<Text>Hey guys I wanted to share this awesome thing just press
  <Text
    style={{color: 'red'}}
    onPress={() => {Linking.openURL('http://www.example.com/')}}
  >
    here
  </Text>
  to see it in your browser
</Text>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I thought I had tried this method before and got an error, but it works.

Comment: Sorry but onPress method doesn't work for Text node although documents emphasize that it does. Cannot get anywhere

Comment: How do you do inline link with touchable opacity?

Answer (score 1):

this package will help you achieve what you are looking for:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-link

```
<TextLink 
    links = {[
        {
          text: 'consectetur adipiscing',
          onPress: () => Linking.openURL('http://www.example.com/'),
        }
    ]}
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce congue malesuada euismod.
</TextLink>
```

Comment: What does this solution do that the accepted answer doesn't do?

Comment: Some small, but relevant differences. 1) it will allow a change in the onPress style. The Text component doesn't have an onPressIn/onPressOut prop so you can't handle the style for that case. 2) better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I feel more confident with **[this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink)** as it has more **Weekly downloads**
Besides that it has been working for 1 year and a half on one of projects I work on. Haven't experienced any problems yet

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned libraries look solid.  I needed something a little different, so I rolled my own component.  Sharing it here, in case it helps someone else.

The below allows one to compose a string with n embedded links in it.  It allows one to give a global text style, global link style and then overrides for individual text and link snippets.

```js
// EmbeddedLinks.tsx

import { StyleProp, Text, TextStyle } from "react-native"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-native"

export type TextSnippet = {
    text: string
    style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
    destination?: string
}

export const EmbeddedLinks: React.FC<{
    textSnippets: Array<TextSnippet>
    linkStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
    textStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
}> = ({ 
    textSnippets, 
    linkStyle = { color: 'blue' }, 
    textStyle = {} 
}) => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    return <Text style={textStyle || {}} >
        {textSnippets.map(({ text, style = {}, destination }) => {
            let props: {
                style: StyleProp<TextStyle>
                onPress?: () => unknown
            }
            if (destination) {
                props = {
                    onPress: () => navigate(destination),
                    style: [linkStyle, style]
                }
            } else {
                props = {
                    style: [textStyle, style]
                }
            }
            return <Text {...props}>{text}</Text>
        })}
    </Text >
}
```

Usage looks like...

```js
import { EmbeddedLinks } from "../components/EmbeddedLinks"

const LinkedEmbeddedText = () => (
    <EmbeddedLinks
        textStyle={{
            fontSize: 16
        }}
        textSnippets={[
            { text: 'Either ' },
            {
                text: 'go here',
                destination: 'path/to/here',
            },
            {
                text: ' or ',
                style: { fontWeight: 'bold' }
            },
            {
                text: 'go there',
                destination: 'path/to/there',
            },
            { text: '!' },
        ]}
    />
)
```

The result looks like...
[image]